# SIGABORT with LibC 6 on ARM 7 Sitara

Tags: c++, qt, sigabrt

## I'm developing on the following system

- PC with Qt 4.8, GCC > 4.4, Intel processors with Debian 7 AMD64 with QCreator (Try with Core 2 Duo et i7)
- ARM 335X Ti Sitara dev kit (tactil, wifi) with a modified Debian 7

When I use my program on a computer I encounter no problem.

When the Sitara launches the program, a SIGABRT appear in 30 - 60 seconds and kills my app with this message:

```
 *** glibc detected *** /home/root/myApp : corrupted double-linked list: 0x00d3e440 ***
```

## Solutions I have tried unsuccessfully:

- Check QML Debug
- Try to use **gdbserver** (on Sitara) and **gdb** (on my computer), it results in *SIGABRT* in lib C 6 with ASM (all the time on the same address)
- Try to install **Valgrind** on the Sitara, but I can't
- Use the option: `export MALLOC_CHECK_=0` but *SIGBUS* appears and other bad errors
- Try to get the latest Sitara SDK
- Try to reinstall everything several times
- Try to use another Qt app
- Check the Sitara RAM
- Try to take a very basic Rev on SVN

Are there any other solutions I should try to get rid of this error?

(Ti forum : http://e2e.ti.com/support/arm/sitara_arm/f/791/t/363615.aspx)

Comment: Try turning ON malloc checking in the PC build by linkng with the `-lmcheck` option. Then you may discover the bugs in the PC build where they are easier to deal with.

Comment: Thanks you :) I've a track ! `QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 10 and type 'Read', disabling...
Aborted` I look it this week end :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solve, the company that creating our Sitara version give to us an Kernel with bug.

Have a good day